# Why must Lie superalgebras always contain both $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$?

Tags: supersymmetry, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry, superalgebra

In four dimensions Lie superalgebras naturally arise by relaxing the presupposition in the Coleman-Mandula theorem that the symmetry is not classified by a Lie algebra.  It is then typically stated that the spin-statistics theorem requires the newly allowed generators to form half-integer spin representations of the Poincare group and that, by the Haag–Łopuszański–Sohnius theorem, they must be in either the representation ($\frac{1}{2}$,0) or its conjugate (0,$\frac{1}{2}$).  The 4d $\mathcal{N}=1$ super-poincare algebra contains both of these, labeled as $Q$ and $\bar{Q}\equiv Q^*$.

Originally, my question was "why can we not have a chiral superalgebra in $d=4$?".  In other even dimensions we do not in general have to include both the left and right handed representations as supercharges. This can be seen in $d=2\mod 4$ where algebras with chiral supercharges such as the 2d $\mathcal{N}=(2,2)$ or 6d $\mathcal{N}=(2,0)$ theories exist.  However, the reason this is possible is because in these dimensions the Weyl representations are self-conjugate, and thus, although it does not contain both representiations, it $\textit{does}$ still contain $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$.  This seems to imply an implicit assumption that the algebra must always contain $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$, and in fact this assumption is made in chapter 1 of Wess and Bagger to prove that the higher half-integer representations do not appear in the superalgebra.

So, if I am understanding this correctly, the proof that we can't include generators in representations higher than spin-1/2 seems to require this assumption that $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$ are both in the algebra. Why is this a reasonable assumption to make? It seems if we did not include it we could have a much more extensive superalgebra.